# stored procedure to get name using two table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

```
tbl_fee_payment_history


pk_int_fph_id  fk_int_student_id     int_fph_amount         dat_fph_date


    1          1                          10000               2013-12-11
    2          2                           5000               2013-11-11
    3          1                           5000               2013-12-16
    4          3                           5000               2013-10-19


tbl_students

pk_int_student_id   fk_int_user_id       vchr_student_name  

1                    2                    alex      
2                    3                    johnson   
3                    4                    ram           
4                    5                    mary
```

How to create stored procedure to find out the name of the student, fees paid during a particular month and year

as like : `csp_students(2013,10);`
results:

```
    .name.
     mary
```

Comment: Isn't it RAM who paid fees in the 10th month?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake ....not mary  is ram !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.`vchr_student_name` FROM
tbl_fee_payment_history f 
INNER JOIN tbl_students s
ON f.`fk_int_student_id` = s.`pk_int_student_id`
WHERE YEAR(`dat_fph_date`) = 2013 AND 
MONTH(`dat_fph_date`) = 10
```

For getting dayname there is a mysql handy function **[*DAYNAME*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)**

```
mysql> SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
        -> 'Saturday'
```

Comment: can you  plz tell me "how can we check the date is monday or sunday " if 14-02-1994 in this the day 14 is monday , sunday or what else ....how can i get it from sql and dispalay ?